# presentationcore cannot load into silverlight application

Tags: silverlight

I have created a silverlight application and I couldn't load PresenetationCore.dll into it.

I need to convert the UIElements into image or Bitmap.

How to do it...?

Answer (score 1):

PresentationCore references standard .NET core dlls.  You can only load into a silverlight application dlls that are specifically referencing silverlight core dlls.

To convert UIElements in to a Bitmap you need to use Silverlight's `WritableBitmap` class and its `Render` method.